# Python script to set all subtitles for movies and shows in plex to English non forced subtitles

Tags: python, plex

**Edit:** This code is working and completed. Thanks to all who helped! Feel free to use this code for your own purposes. I will be running this code periodically on my home server to set preferred subtitles. Cheers!

This code was created with the help of [ChatGPT Open AI](https://chat.openai.com/) and further edited and completed by me. It uses [Plex Python Api](https://github.com/pkkid/python-plexapi). It will set all movies and shows in your local Plex library to English non forced subtitles by default. The subtitle selections will apply to your Plex profile and be remembered on other devices. Assuming your Plex subtitles settings are setup in your server settings Plex will default to Forced Subtitles by default when they are available for a given item. Plex will not allow you to prefer non forced subtitles natively hence why this script was created.

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75038161/9196825) below for the code.

Also posted on:

- [Github](https://github.com/RileyXX/PlexPreferNonForcedSubs)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/13ttswd/tool_for_setting_default_subtitles_to_english/)
- [Plex Forums](https://forums.plex.tv/t/python-script-to-set-all-movies-and-shows-in-plex-to-use-english-non-forced-subtitles/825871)

Comment: Looking at the API documentation for the `Media` object [here](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/media.html#plexapi.media.Media), I'd guess that you want to do: `part = movie.media[0].parts[0]  # get first item in the parts list` and then `partsid = part.id`.

Comment: @MattPitkin Thank you! I was having a hard time trying understand how to call the objects in this api. It makes so much sense now. I was able to successfully get the part id using your method. Now just need to clean up the code, test run it and make sure it all works. Then I can publish this as finished. This will be a neat little script to add to my plex script collection. I'm going to run this periodically along with my other scripts! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code:

```
from plexapi.server import PlexServer
from plexapi.media import SubtitleStream
import os

def main():
    
    # Connect to Plex Media Server. Replace PLEX_TOKEN below with your Plex token. How to get token: https://www.plexopedia.com/plex-media-server/general/plex-token/
    baseurl = 'http://localhost:32400'
    token = 'PLEX_TOKEN'
    
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    token_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'token.txt')
    
    try:
        with open(token_file, 'r') as f:
            token = f.read().strip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    if token == 'PLEX_TOKEN':
        print(f'\nHow to get your Plex token: https://www.plexopedia.com/plex-media-server/general/plex-token/\n')
        token = input("Enter your Plex token: ")
        with open(token_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(token)

    plex = PlexServer(baseurl, token)

    table_headers = ['Title', 'Year', 'Status', 'Changes']
    title_width = 70
    year_width = 5
    status_width = 20
    changes_width = 8

    print("\n" + "-" * 114 + "\nMovies\n" + "-" * 114)
    print(f'\033[1m\033[96m{" | ".join([h.ljust(title_width if i == 0 else year_width if i == 1 else status_width if i == 2 else changes_width) for i, h in enumerate(table_headers)])}\033[0m')

    for section in plex.library.sections():
        if section.type == 'movie':
            for movie in section.all():
                movie.reload()
                english_subs = [stream for stream in movie.subtitleStreams() if stream.languageCode == 'eng']
                non_forced_english_subs = [stream for stream in english_subs if not stream.forced or (hasattr(stream, 'title') and stream.title is not None and 'forced' not in stream.title.lower())]
                forced_english_subs = [stream for stream in english_subs if stream.forced or (hasattr(stream, 'title') and stream.title is not None and 'forced' in stream.title.lower())]
                part = movie.media[0].parts[0]
                partsid = part.id
                if forced_english_subs and non_forced_english_subs:
                    non_forced_english_subs[0].setDefault()
                    print(f'\033[92m{movie.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(movie.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"English (Non-Forced)".ljust(status_width)} | {"Y".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')
                elif non_forced_english_subs and not forced_english_subs:
                    print(f'{movie.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(movie.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"English".ljust(status_width)} | {"N".ljust(changes_width)}')
                elif not non_forced_english_subs and not forced_english_subs:
                    print(f'\033[91m{movie.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(movie.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"No Subtitles Found".ljust(status_width)} | {"N".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')
                else:
                    print(f'\033[91m{movie.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(movie.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"English (Forced)".ljust(status_width)} | {"N (Error)".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')


    table_headers = ['Title', 'Year', 'Season #', 'Episode #', 'Status', 'Changes']
    title_width = 42
    year_width = 5
    season_width = 11
    episode_width = 11
    status_width = 20
    changes_width = 8
    season_row_width = 4
    episode_row_width = 3

    print("\n" + "-" * 114 + "\nShows\n" + "-" * 114)
    print(f'\033[1m\033[96m{" | ".join([h.ljust(title_width if i == 0 else year_width if i == 1 else season_width if i == 2 else episode_width if i == 3 else status_width if i == 4 else changes_width) for i, h in enumerate(table_headers)])}\033[0m')

    for section in plex.library.sections():
        if section.type == 'show':
            for show in section.all():
                show.reload()
                for episode in show.episodes():
                    show.reload()
                    episode.reload()
                    english_subs = [stream for stream in episode.subtitleStreams() if stream.languageCode == 'eng']
                    non_forced_english_subs = [stream for stream in english_subs if not stream.forced or (hasattr(stream, 'title') and stream.title is not None and 'forced' not in stream.title.lower())]
                    forced_english_subs = [stream for stream in english_subs if stream.forced or (hasattr(stream, 'title') and stream.title is not None and 'forced' in stream.title.lower())]
                    part = episode.media[0].parts[0]
                    partsid = part.id
                    if forced_english_subs and non_forced_english_subs:
                        non_forced_english_subs[0].setDefault()
                        print(f'\033[92m{show.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(show.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"Season " + str(episode.seasonNumber).ljust(season_row_width)} | {"Episode " + str(episode.index).ljust(episode_row_width)} | {"English (Non-Forced)".ljust(status_width)} | {"Y".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')
                    elif non_forced_english_subs and not forced_english_subs:
                        print(f'{show.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(show.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"Season " + str(episode.seasonNumber).ljust(season_row_width)} | {"Episode " + str(episode.index).ljust(episode_row_width)} | {"English".ljust(status_width)} | {"N".ljust(changes_width)}')
                    elif not non_forced_english_subs and not forced_english_subs and not forced_english_subs:
                        print(f'\033[91m{show.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(show.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"Season " + str(episode.seasonNumber).ljust(season_row_width)} | {"Episode " + str(episode.index).ljust(episode_row_width)} | {"No Subtitles Found".ljust(status_width)} | {"N".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')
                    else:
                        print(f'\033[91m{show.title[:title_width].ljust(title_width)} | {str(show.year).ljust(year_width)} | {"Season " + str(episode.seasonNumber).ljust(season_row_width)} | {"Episode " + str(episode.index).ljust(episode_row_width)} | {"English (Forced)".ljust(status_width)} | {"N (Error)".ljust(changes_width)}\033[0m')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```